# Change Counting With Bills in C

Tags: c, math, count, stdin, modulo

I am working on a program that takes in an amount owed and amount paid then calculates the amount of change needed to be given using fifty dollar bills, twenty dollar bills, etc. and also using quarters dimes and nickels.

**This is the code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    double owed, paid;

    printf("Enter amount owed: ");
    scanf("%lf", &owed);

    printf("Enter amount paid: ");
    scanf("%lf", &paid);

    int owing = paid - owed;

    int fifty;
    if (owing > 0)
    {
        fifty = owing/50;
        printf("\n%d fifty dollar bill\n", fifty);
    }
    else
        printf("0 fifty dollar bill\n");
    owing = owing % 50;

    int twenty;
    if (owing > 0)
    {
        twenty = owing / 20;
        printf("%d twenty dollar bill\n", twenty);
    }
    else
        printf("0 twenty dollar bill\n");
    owing = owing % 20;


    int ten;
    if (owing > 0)
    {
        ten = owing / 10;
        printf("%d ten dollar bill\n", ten);
    }
    else
        printf("0 ten dollar bill\n");
    owing = owing % 10;

    int five;
    if (owing > 0)
    {
        five = owing / 5;
        printf("%d five dollar bill\n", five);
    }
    else
        printf("0 five dollar bill\n");
    owing = owing % 5;

    int toonie;
    if (owing > 0)
    {
        toonie = owing / 2;
        printf("%d two dollar coin\n", toonie);
    }
    else
        printf("0 two dollar coin\n");
    owing = owing % 2;

    int quarter;
    if (owing > 0)
    {
        quarter = owing / 25;
        printf("%d quarter\n", quarter);
    }
    else
        printf("0 quarter\n");
    owing = owing % 25;

    int dime;
    if (owing > 0)
    {
        dime = owing / 10;
        printf("%d dime\n", dime);
    }
    else
        printf("0 dime\n");
    owing = owing % 10;

    int nickel;
    if (owing > 0)
    {
        nickel = owing / 5;
        printf("%d nickel\n", nickel);
    }
    else
        printf("0 nickel\n");
    owing = owing % 5;

    

    
    return 0;
}
```

**This is the current output**

```
Enter amount owed: 16.50
Enter amount paid: 140.65

2 fifty dollar bill 
1 twenty dollar bill
0 ten dollar bill   
0 five dollar bill  
2 two dollar coin   
0 quarter
0 dime
0 nickel
```

**This is the needed output:**

```
Enter amount owed: 16.50
Enter amount paid: 140.65

2 fifty dollar bill 
1 twenty dollar bill  
2 two dollar coin   
1 dime
1 nickel
```

My issue is when the program gets to the cent calculation it doesn't give me back any cents. I have a feeling it has something to do with the fact that my "owing" is of **type int**. I have tried changing it to float but I don't know where to go after that. I am also a beginner to the "C" language and man is it frustrating... an early thankyou to whomever can give me a hand!

Comment: "*it has something to do with the fact that my "owing" is of type int*". That's one of the problems. By doing that you lose the fractional/cents part. Convert the input values from dollars to cents and then do all your calculations in cents. That way it will be fine to work with `int` values.

Comment: `quarter = owing / 25;` That's another problem. `owing` is in dollars but `25` is in cents. So the maths will be wrong as the units are different. Again, operating in cents from the start will solve this problem.

Comment: I converted the number into a full integer meaning "12415" but it still gives me no cents, i dont exactly know what im doing wrong for the cents

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]! Not only is it mandatory for this kind of question here, it also helps you find the error yourself. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

**update**

I made a second variable in the beginning to store the cents in `variablex = paid*100 - owed*100` and used that for my cent calculation by making the variable hold only the cents `variablex = variablex % 100`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can make your calculation in one function to get an better overview of your program. I did this with the `calc` function. Also I compiled the values in one array and their names in another array of the same size with the same order.

```
#include <stdio.h>

double dol_val[] = {50.0, 20.0, 10.0, 5.0, 2.0, 0.25, 0.10, 0.05};
const char * dol_name[] = {
    "fifty dollar bill",
    "twenty dollar bill",
    "ten dollar bill",
    "five dollar bill",
    "two dollar coin",
    "quarter",
    "dime",
    "nickel"
};
double calc(double owing_in, double bill, char *bill_name)
{
    double owing_out = owing_in;
    int bill_counter = 0;
    
    if(owing_out > 0)
    {
        bill_counter = (int)(owing_out / bill);
        if(bill_counter > 0)
        {
            printf("%d %s\n", bill_counter, bill_name);
            owing_out -= bill_counter * bill;
        }
    }
    
    return owing_out;    
}

int main(){
    double owed, paid;

    printf("Enter amount owed: ");
    scanf("%lf", &owed);

    printf("Enter amount paid: ");
    scanf("%lf", &paid);

    double owing = paid - owed;

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(dol_val); i++)
    {
        owing = calc(owing, dol_val[i], dol_name[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The functions gets called every loop cycle with the bill value and name from biggest to smallest. It will only print the bills that have a counter value > 0. And it will return the remaining owing value to the `owing` variable.

In the `calc` function I replaced the modulo operation. Modulo would be fine if you just using `int` variables. The whole function uses double values for the owing value. So you can make a simple division to get the number of bills that are in the remaining owing value, even for the cent values.